# How to know whether my Xperia Ray's bootloader is locked or unlocked one

Tags: bootloader, sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

Title says all, but again a bit background

I would like to know whether the bootloader on my xperia ray is locked or unlocked one. I bought it from ebay & with seller warranty (or you can say no warranty). It was a great deal & I didn't need warranty too as I was going to root it.

I haven't done anything to unlock my boot loader till now. Used x-parts (auto CWM installer) to test some roms. How do I know the phone I received, has bootloader locked or unlocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to flash the original firmware for your phone, then dial `*#*#7378423#*#*` on your dialer app and navigate to `service menu -> service info -> configuration`. It should be indicated there.

Comment: I know that but that means Bootloader **can** be unlocked or not. isn't it? The menu says `Bootloader Unlock allowed`

Comment: @Web-E, yes. If you have an unlocked bootloader, that should have been replaced with an actual indication that your bootloader is **already** unlocked. Otherwise, it will just say that the bootloader is unlockable or not. I forgot the exact wordings it used on mine (Xperia owner too).

Comment: Ok it just says `Bootloader unlock allowed : Yes`

Comment: Then that means your bootloader is **not** unlocked but it **can** be unlocked. :)

Answer (score 0):

It should say, "Bootloader Unlocked: Yes"